# How can the email addresses be case sensitive for AWS SES alone?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, gmail, amazon-ses

I am planning to use Amazon SES to send email. But this page says email addresses are case sensitive. How can it be  case sensitive when email providers like Google and Yahoo are not case-sensitive. Gmail doesn't differentiate a123456@gmail.com vs. A123456@GMAIL.COM. It still sends to same single owner of that email address. Though I identify users as unique using their email addresses by saving in database, this sounds fishy.

Comment: Domain name is still case insensitive in SES, only the username is case sensitive in SES.

Comment: So SES will handle a@gmail.com and A@gmail.com differently? But they are same users. Does this settings vary from domain to domain?

Comment: All domains are case insensitive. Usernames (the ones before @) are case sensitive irrespective of domains.

Answer (score 8):

Any email address will have two parts *localmailbox@domain.com*.

1. domain.com: This is your domain name and this part will always be case insensitive
2. localmailbox: This part is case sensitive - theoretically different cases would point to different mail boxes. But to avoid confusion email providers like gmail enforce case insensitive mailboxes.

Why amazon has it as case-sensitive - this can be because of the [RFC-5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321)  which states

> SMTP implementations MUST take care to preserve the case of mailbox local-parts. In particular, for some hosts, the user "smith" is different from the user "Smith". However, exploiting the case sensitivity of mailbox local-parts impedes interoperability and is discouraged.